# IOGear 2-Port USB KVM Switch doesn't shows my laptop monitor

Tags: switch, kvm-switch

i bought IOGear 2-Port USB KVM Switch (http://www.iogear.com/product/GCS22U/) and connected it to my desktop and laptop.

The desktop works great, and i can see that the remote switch between the two views, however, i don't see my laptop monitor on the main screen. I have IBM thinkpad T-42 and i clicked on the monitor switch function buttong (Fn + F7), but nothing show's up.

anyone has any idea? am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Windows XP, Vista or 7? If you connect the monitor directly to the laptop, does that work? How about connecting the desktop to the ports you're trying to connect the laptop to so we can eliminate the possibility of a failed KVM?

There is a good chance that Windows simply has not activated the second monitor and you simply need to enable it in display properties.